# how do i insert large amounts of data to google datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, fixtures

Should I write a script to "put" all of those data in? But wouldn't that be silly, since I would have to reinsert the data every time the app starts?

Someone suggest something called fixtures? How do I use that exactly?

The data I would insert:

```
id: int,
name: varchar,
addr: varchar,
email: varchar,
phone: varchar,
ssn: varchar,
```

Comment: "I would have to reinsert the data every time the app starts?" - er? Are you referring to the development server? Why would you need to load 'large amounts' of data into your test environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Bulkloader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) you can upload data in CSV format.